# "cp -a" (Copy in Archive Mode) does not influence "stat" command in "Time of last change"

Tags: bash, backup, stat, cp

I'll provide the following script to reproduce the problem:

```
mkdir a
touch a/f
sleep 1
cp -a a b
stat --printf="%u %g %a %z\n" a/f
stat --printf="%u %g %a %z\n" b/f
```

The result for the two `stat` calls will **differ** in the **timestamps**:

```
1000 100 644 2015-04-05 10:53:35.736399836 +0200
1000 100 644 2015-04-05 10:53:36.740399841 +0200
```

But the manual of `cp` tells, that `-a` should preserve the timestamps.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I ensure timestamps are kept at the copy in a way I can test for it?

I tried this at Xubuntu 14.04. Thx for any help!

Ps (Important):

I just tried to access timestamps over `ls`, there I don't have the same behavior:

```
$ ls -l --full-time a/
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo bar 0 2015-04-05 10:53:35.736399836 +0200 f
$ ls -l --full-time b/
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo bar 0 2015-04-05 10:53:35.736399836 +0200 f
```

Am I checking the wrong thing with my stat command? I want to find out if a file as been "changed" by comparing it to a copy in the backup...

Comment: Maybe I should use `%y`, time of last modification? I first thought this is only meant to be for changes of e.g. access-right and stuff, but it seems also to be updated for file content changes... this is maybe what `ls` is using in my example...

Comment: is it that "last change" also includes "birth-time"? this would then mean, that last change could be YOUNGER then last modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` prints 3 different times:

> - Access - the last time the file was **read**
> - Modify - the last time the **file** was modified (content has been modified)
> - Change - the last time **meta data** of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

This explains why the *Change* time differs between `a/f` to `b/f` (metadata was updated),
while the *Modify* time is the same (file's content didn't change upon `cp`).

---

```
  File: `a/f'
...
Access: 2015-04-05 16:15:22.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2015-04-05 16:15:13.000000000 +0300
Change: 2015-04-05 16:15:13.000000000 +0300
```

---

```
  File: `b/f'
...
Access: 2015-04-05 16:15:22.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2015-04-05 16:15:13.000000000 +0300
Change: 2015-04-05 16:19:49.000000000 +0300
```

Comment: no. cause it's a different file with a different location - that's part of the metadata. neither `-p` will keep the metadata.